How to play animation with desired framerate?
I've created an animation for export and want to see how it will look in realtime. When I'm trying to play it in blender I'm getting ~11 fps. In solid mode I'm getting ~20 fps. How can I play this animation with, for example, 60 fps?

Just to clarify, you're trying to extend the amount of frames you have?

@Starry-EyedDonut, no, I just want to make it look like in game, where I have 60 fps. I just don't know how to explain it with other words... For now I have 20 frames per second, I want to see 60 frames per second.

if you "just" wanna see it in viewport (without rendering) i would recommend clicking "simplify" in render settings and maybe open that panel and set all subdivision to 0. if you have particle settings, set children to 0 as well. If you still don't reach 60 fps, try hiding "expensive" meshes by hiding them or just showing as bounds e.g.

@Chris simplify has no effect for me, I don't have any subdivs, and I have only one character's mesh with 58k verticies. And I don't have particles too, so it doesn't help me. Can I somehow "pre render" animation and play it with desired fps? I don't need to exactly "render" it, I just need to see it in viewport.

yes, you can e.g. use viewport render animation which is very quick and watch that after it is ready.

@Chris how can I do it?

Click in the viewport menu on View > Viewport Render Animation to do it. If you are in camera view, it renders from the camera, but you can render the viewport from any perspective you are currently looking at the scene.

By the way, it is a common misconception to think Blender would always playback the viewport with the desired framerate, especially with heavy scenes it is hard for Blender to keep with the framerate while computing everything on the fly. Read more about why the FPS setting exists in the first place in my comments here: How do I fix low fps while moving bones in pose mode

Blender does not do things like a game engine.
The whole pipeline is designed for a maximum flexibility and an ease of development within the constrains of it been an open software. If you see it lagging it means in this case Blender is reserved for or can do things that a game engine could not. It is sacrificing performance for capability. It can miss some critical optimizations but the main reason is the paradigm of it being a DCC.
For example: a game engine can utilize a GPU in an efficient manner. Blender would do the animation on a CPU and recompute the geometry in an "honest way" every frame to keep it available for other things.
Look for some other examples searching for "disney animation process 3d". They are not doing or previewing the animation with every bell and whistle turn on.
What you want is to search for "blender optimize animation playback".
